# VxWorks Stack Frame Unusually Large

Tags: c, assembly, x86, vxworks

I'm looking at some optimized assembly code targeting the x86 (32 bit) platform and VxWorks 6.8.  I have five local variables (aside from the three passed parameters) and these five variables are typed as follows:  `char[200], char*, int, int, fd_set`.  The three passed variables are typed as `int, int, bool`.  When I look at the disassembly, the stack frame is created as:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push edi
push esi
push ebx
sub esp,0x10fc
```

What I'm curious about is the last line as it allocates 4348 bytes on the stack for the five locals, which seems like far too much space.  Also: the second local (`char*`) is used to walk each byte in the first local (`char[200]`).  Any insight into why so much space is allocated would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fd_set` contains among other thing an array of type `SOCKET` with potentially `FD_SETSIZE` (could be 64?) members... so I would suspect that the big size is not from the `char[]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fd_set` typically contains 1024 bits, or 128 bytes.

Chances are you are passing `fd_set` by value to some other functions, creating unnamed temporaries in the process.

You can compile the source with `-fdump-tree-all`, and examine resulting output files. You should be able to see all the temporaries GCC created.